# Android build tools not detected

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I am developing Android application using Ionic framework (Ionic is built on top of Apache Cordova). When I try to build my app, I get an error, which states that build tools are missing.

Error:

```
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
```

I am using windows, and I have Android SDK tools installed (at C:\tools), also I have used sdkmanager to install platform-tools (at C:\platform-tools) and android26 and android27 platforms (at C:\platforms\android-26 and C:\platforms\android-27).

My ANDROID_HOME enviroment variable is set to C:\tools and I have included all of the following locations in my path:

- C:\tools
- C:\tools\bin
- C:\platform-tools
- C:\platforms

I believe I am missing something, what do I have to do/fix for my build to succeedd. What are those build tools that I do not have installed?

Comment: It is not complaining about not finding your SDK. It is complaining about not finding build tools version 19.1.0. So open android studio and open your SDK Manager --> press SDK Tools -> press show package details -> look for 19.1.0 (or higher) and pick one, or more -> press ok -> resync

Comment: I do not have Android Studio,I have Android SDK Tools CLI, how can I install those build tools using sdkmanager from terminal?

Comment: hmm I would use the sdkmanager.bat since android.bat is deprecated

Comment: it is located in your sdk-path/tools/bin/sdkmanager.bat

Comment: Ok, but what should I type in, I am not that much of an Android developer... Is this right: sdkmanager "build-tools;19.1.0"?

Comment: yeah that is correct but it should work without ""

Comment: I will try that now, and I will add "C:\build-tools" to my PATH and try again. I will add comment about my results.

Comment: Also, it would benefit you to have everything in one folder instead of being spread out all over your C drive, so put everything in C:\SDK and change your paths whenver you have time

Comment: Ok, so I downloaded build tools 19.1.0 and 28.0.3 (just to be sure), and added build-tools to my PATH, and build is still failing...

Comment: so what's the error now? You can also actually see if the build tools has been crreated by checking your build-tools folder

Comment: just to be 100% sure what you are doing, please just run sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26" and then sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"

Comment: Still the same error, and yes, build-tools folder is created.

Comment: Will tun that now

Comment: do this first. create an SDK folder in your C:/ then set ANDROID_HOME to C:/SDK and put your tools etc in that folder. ANDROID_HOME should not be set to tools/.

Comment: ^ is probably why it can't find it. because it is navigating in the wrong path.

Comment: Yeah, I moved tools, build-tools, platform-tools and platforms folders to sdk folder in my C drive, and changed ANDROID_HOME to C:\sdk, everything works now. Would you like to answer my question, so I can mark it is solution?

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it worked for you. Sorry for not realizing this earlier, I am very sleepy hehe

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set "ANDROID_HOME" to your sdk tools folder. This is causing an error in the relative navigation used by Cordova.

**Solution:** Create a new folder "SDK" in your C drive as such `C:\SDK`. Now add all of the sdk stuff into that directory. Finally, change your "ANDROID_HOME" path to `C:\SDK`